# Как сделать прокрутку QToolBar PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtabwidget, qtoolbar, qmainwindow

Пытаюсь создать вкладки как у браузеров. 
Как при большом количестве виджетов на **`QToolBar`** сделать их прокрутку с помощью стрелочек: влево и вправо? \

Или лучше использовать другой виджет вместо `QToolBar` для таких целей?

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.tool = QToolBar(self)

        for i in range(100):
            button = QPushButton()
            self.tool.addWidget(button)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил следующее:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):                             # !!! QMainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabwidget)
        
        for i in range(100):
            self.tabwidget.addTab(QWidget(), "tab-{}".format(i))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Уже разобрался. Если кому понадобится, то можно сделать так:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.i = 0
        self.tool = QToolBar()
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.bb = QScrollArea()
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        
        for i in range(100):
            button = QPushButton()
            self.tool.addWidget(button)
            
        self.bb.setWidget(self.tool)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.bb)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```